# Caching in Service Oriented Architecture in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, service, soa

I want to create a good caching mechanism for a Service Oriented Architecture in ASP.NET.

The caching can be done at cleint tier, web tier or service tier

But in my case i want to do it at Service Tier.

The strategies can possibly be **Write-Through** but there will also no problem with **Data Event Driven**

Whether there are some open source libraries for the same.

The services can be either ASP.NET XMl Web Service (ASMX) or WCF one.

If possible can you also provide the code since i am new to caching

Thanks.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both WCF and ASMX come with strong caching support, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443.aspx Next to that, there is caching support straight out of the box in the BCL, see http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/object-caching----net-4/37

Answer (score 0):

There are many Microsoft and third party cache frameworks each with their own strengths and weaknesses. Some reading with code and tutorials to get you started.

[Building better data-driven apps with MS distributed caching.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx)

[Enterprise library 5 caching Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx)

**EDIT**

As mentioned there is also the .Net 4 [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx) API.

Comment: Enterprise library 5 Caching application block have been replaced by System.Runtime.Caching (BCL support)